# actionview-4.2.4 - uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

```
C:\Users\Clarion Smith\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-
```

My problem is very common in Ruby and Rails. Though I went through different stackoverflow answers, I could not find anything specific which would fix my error.

I tried reinstalling lower version of the railites gem but the same error keeps popping. I tried reinstalling all the gems that were throwing errors and still the problem doesnt seem to go away. Many articles indicated that this is a compatibility issue. But when I tried reinstalling a lower version of the railties gem(4.0.0), the command prompt still asked me to upgrade to the latest version in order to continue. I also installed 'Passenger' web server to check the compatibility and a similar error popped up but this time with the passenger gem. Please look into this accordingly. I am also copying below the gem file.

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
#Bundle for Passenge r web server
gem 'passenger'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
#gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets

#gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'rack', '~> 1.6.0'
gem 'rspec-rails', :group => [:development, :test]
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views

#gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library

#gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

#gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

#gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.

#gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember fixing this error this way:

1. Uninstall `railties` gem.
2. Then install an older version of the `rails` gem (`4.0.0` in my case because that was the one from the tutorial).

This fixed the issue for me once.

Did you try these steps?

Comment: @K M Rakibul Islam - I tried this. But the problem i get is that the command prompt does not allow me to run rails until i upgrade it to 4.2.2 which is the latest version. I am pasting the snippet below. C:\Users\Clarion Smith\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
Could not find railties-4.2.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems. I ran bundle install and this updates to 4.2.4(latest version automatically).

Comment: hmm, seems like things have changed than before. Can you share the tutorial link that you are following?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEjkWRbLS84&index=4&list=PL5bVh07ELMxT8OsaX01SjpqmsWCk-eHtp

Answer (score 1):

Check your `Gemfile.lock` file for the version of nokogiri used. I experienced the same issue with `nokogiri 1.6.6.4`. It installs successfully with necessary dlls but for some reason it doesn't play nice on windows.

**What worked for me**, hope this works for you too

1. Put `gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.6.2'` in your gem file
2. Uninstall other versions of nokogiri
3. Download nokogiri 1.6.6.2 gem from [here](https://github.com/paulgrant999/ruby-2.2.2-nokogiri-1.6.6.2-x86-x64-mingw32.gem) compiled by paulgrant999 for ruby 2.2. Both x86 and x64 versions are available, for now. Author states repo will be deleted soon.
4. Install using command `gem install --local path-to-gem/filename.gem`
5. Bundle install in your project directory. It may ask you to run `bundle update nokogiri` to update dependencies. `rails s` should now start the server.

Answer (score 1):

For me I was able to get around this with

```
gem pristine --all
```