# in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just started learning Ruby on Rails. I installed all the related softwares and started exploring the same. When I try to start the default server in Rails (WEBrick), I am getting the following error.

```
C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>': uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper (NameError)
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `require'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:7:in `<class:Template>'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:6:in `<module:WebConsole>'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `require'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from C:/Temp/Rails-Project/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in`require'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in`block in server'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`tap'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`server'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
    from C:/Apps/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Upon research in SOF, found from [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28999906/3017645) and [other link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32879550/3017645) that the nokogiri needs to be updated in the Gemfile. I updated and executed the Bundle Install command. Even after that, its not working. Please suggest me the ways to fix it. FYI, I am using the latest versions of gems.

I also updated my Gemfile with

> gem 'rack', '~> 1.6.0'

It did not work.

Comment: Well I would personally recommend you using linux for RoR development. Windows has lot of issues running RoR and webrick server too. You ll keep getting into such problems more often. I strongly recommend you to use linux.

Answer (score 0):

Install an older version of rails (4.0.0) because I think windows doesn't have stable version of rails > 4.0. 
Change the version in gemfile.